# Configuring sublimeREPL to build to new window or same tab

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I am just now getting started with Sublime Text 3 and SublimeREPL for Python usage and I am beginning to enjoy it. I am trying to configure my space to be as efficient for me as possible. So far I have configured my SublimeREPL to reuse the tab when running  code, namely:

Adding:

```
"view_id": "*REPL* [python]",
```

in the "repl_python_run" command in SublimeREPL\config\Python\Main.sublime-menu,

and then to changing:

```
if view.name() == view_id:
   found = view
   window.focus_view(found)    # <-- add this line
   break
```

in SublimeREPL\sublimerepl.py.

As a result, I am able to reuse the same tab after a build. I am looking for two possible enhancements to my space:

1) If i disattach the tab that runs python in interactive code and build again, it creates a new tab. How can I have it so that when I build, interactive mode launches in a new window and I can reuse that window everytime I build?

2) How can I have the bottom of my Sublime Text have an interactive output, similar to RStudio? This way I can see the results of each build in the same window, and make modifications as necessary without switching tabs/opening new windows.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you use it nowadays? I'm considering replacing my IDE with SublimeREPL...

Comment: hi i am also interested in if you got it to work?

Comment: any advance on this until now?